# Why does eutectic point have three phases, but consolute point have only two phases?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, phase

At eutectic point, there are three phases: solid A, solid B and homogenous liquid phase containing both A and B.

But at consolute point, we are told it has 2 phases: liquid A and liquid B.

Why isn't there a homogenous phase containing both liquid A and B at consolute point just like an eutectic point?

Answer (score 1):

It would make more sense to compare the eutectic point with the azeotropic point for a heteroazeotrope (not for a typically seen homoazeotrope). You can see the similarity between them in the following two phase diagrams, both showing three phases at the eutectic and azeotropic points.

The eutectic point is the point for a solid/liquid equilibrium while the azeotropic point is the point for a liquid/vapor equilibrium. At the eutectic point, in addition to the liquid phase, the solid exists in an eutectic lamellar structure of A and B, or in the case shown below, an eutectic structure of α and β solid solutions rich in Ag and Cu, respectively. Likewise, at the azeotropic point, in addition to the vapor phase, the liquid exists in immiscible layers of liquids rich in X and Y, respectively.

Therefore, in both cases there are three phases, leading to conditional degree of freedom (or variance) of zero, where the word "conditional" refers to a specific pressure and "zero" means a fixed point on the phase diagrams.

[image]

Panel (a) is taken from [libretexts](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/DeVoes_Thermodynamics_and_Chemistry/13%3A_The_Phase_Rule_and_Phase_Diagrams/13.02%3A__Phase_Diagrams-_Binary_Systems).
Panel (b) is taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azeotrope).

Answer (score 0):

I just realised, the 2 phases present in a liquid-liquid solution system with temperature below its solution temperature is a) conjugate solution enriched in A
b) conjugate solution enriched in B

No pure liquid A or pure liquid B phase exists.